# Like button throws javascript error

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-like

I'm trying to put a like-button on a webpage. I've got this in my html-tag:
`xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"`

This after the body-tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); 
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nn_NO/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=184653131620215";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>`
```

And this to display button:

```
<fb:like href="http://fagmobler.no/index.php?kat_id=96&amp;id=2423" send="true" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Nothing shows on my webpage. I only get a JavaScript error saying:

> Cannot set property 'id' of undefined".

And this error refers to the JavaScript function defined in the script-tag. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

you should include the FBML as well in your html tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

also you have to include the og meta tags - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/